# Change li/a tag text on click event of Url.Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In the Razor view there is following html:

```
`<li id="myli"><a href="@Url.Action(MyAction, new { Id = ViewBag.Id })" >TEST</a></li>
```

I can Not change it in any way. Some kind of "Please wait" indicator needs to be displayed while MyAction is in processing.
I have tried many approaches, starting with very simple : change link's text "TEST" to "Please Wait" in $('#myli').click  event. But text changes happen only After return from controller action.

```
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#myli').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();          
        $(this).text("Please Wait"); // displayed only After return from controller action 
        sleep(2000);
)};

function sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

 </script>
}
```

Is there way to change link's text Before action is called ?
Thank you

Comment: post some more info, here you want to show some indicator while the action is in process

Comment: show the code what you tried and how?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$('#myli').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();  //what does event mean????
```

change to:

```
$('#myli').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
```

### UPDATE:

why are you running a loop like that , can't you just use the generic setTimeout ?

```
$('#myli').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).text('Please Wait...');
        setTimeout(function(){alert('Thanks For Waiting!')},5000)
 });
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dw2BY/) in jsfiddle

Comment: I did use what you suggest (just made mistake in my question text), same problem. I also tried to change sleep() values, but it doesn't make difference, sleeps only for 3-4 secs and text always changes After sleep() completed, not before.

Comment: I've tried just with very long loop instead of sleep : same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be wise to use `ajax.actionlink` which will be converted to anchor tag at runtime.

```
    <li id="myli"> @Ajax.ActionLink("TEST", "Action", "Controller", new { Id = ViewBag.Id }, new AjaxOptions
       {
         HttpMethod = "Get",
         OnSuccess = "successFunction",
         OnFailure = "onFailureFunction",
         OnBegin = "startAjax",
         LoadingElementId = "PleaseWaitContainer",
         OnComplete = "endAjax"
        })
</li>
```

You can write a custom class for *PleaseWaitContainer* with the property `display: none`. Rest will be taken care by the ajax call.

```
<div id="PleaseWaitContainer" style="display:none;">Please wait</div>.
```

You can also have java script functions like `startAjax()` and `endAjax()` which can be called at the start and end of the ajax call.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, below link tag has to stay unchanged:

    <li id="myli"><a href="@Url.Action(MyAction, new { Id = ViewBag.Id })" >TEST</a></li>

Comment: if u wrap a <li> around it then the rendered html will be same as you want. I have updated my answer. if you want to go with jquery then Scott's answer is the option